# Eclipse typing code on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, eclipse, text, lines

When I try to type text (between "") in javascript, I have to write everything on 1 line.
I can't press enter because my code woudn't be valid then.

Appearantly you can't type on multiple lines in javascript.
Is this correct or did I make a mistake?

Example:

```
var htmlcode = "<strong>29 juni 2013</strong> <br/> 22u";
//This works

var htmlcode = "<strong>29 juni 2013</strong> 
<br/> 
22u";
//This doesn't work
```

Comment: my eclipses gives me the + sign automatically when I press enter, since yours does not, see Chris's answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: This is weird, when I press the enter key next to my numpad, I don't get a "+".
But when I press the enter key next to my delete key, it gives me a "+".
Weird, but it's fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to break up code to be on multiple lines, what you can do is either of the following:

```
// Concatenate to the string
var htmlcode = "<strong>29 juni 2013</strong> "
    + "<br/> "
    + "22u";
```

or

```
// Use backslashes at the end of each line. May not be supported everywhere,
//   so I'd avoid this approach.
var htmlcode = "<strong>29 juni 2013</strong> \
<br/> \
22u";
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of Eclipse, there is an option that could help.  Go to Preferences -> JavaScript -> Editor -> Typing.  On the page, enable "Wrap automatically" and "Escape text...".  This will ensure that if you press enter while inside of a string, quotes, \n, and + will be added appropriately.